# Setting properties of user control from MainPageViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application I have a MainWindow that contains MainPageView as the Content control. This MainPageView has a search option for user and search results are displayed on this MainPageView user control. The search results are displayed originaly in 2 column styles. User can chose to View details of a particular result by clicking "Details" button on Search result (Every search result is also a user control having description textblock, hyperlink etc.).

So when Details button is clicked, the above MainPageView's results area turns into a Single Column and the 2nd column is used to display the details. I have a UserControl created that can display the details. I am able to show this dialog user control by setting the properties in code behind. But how can I set the properties of the Details user control through MVVM?

Here is XAML for populating results

```
 <ContentControl>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TemplatesVM}" Width="{Binding GridWidth}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding NumColumns}"></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <v:TemplateView Content="{Binding }"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
    </ContentControl>
```

And here is the TemplateVM collection

```
private Collection<TemplatesViewModel> _templatesVM;
public Collection<TemplatesViewModel> TemplatesVM { get { return _templatesVM; } set {     _templatesVM = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TemplatesVM); } }
```

Now when Details button is pressed on a particular search result, **how do I populate the properties in ViewModel of DetailsView?** Here is xaml of showing DetailsView in mainPageView

```
<v:DetailsView ></v:DetailsView>
```

and here is the property of DetailsViewModel object that carries all information to be displayed.

```
public DetailsViewModel DetailsManager { get; set;}
```

Any helpful comments/answers will be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Which is the class that contains object DetailsManager ?

Comment: MainPageViewModel has this object. I fill in this object when Details button is pressed. But how should I bind this object in xaml so that all properties get mapped to the DetailsView's properties?

Comment: So you want to bind DetailsManager's properties to <v:DetailsView>.
Right? For that you have to show that where have you exactly used DetailsView as it will inherit the properties of it's parent. So, please tell the exact location.

Comment: In MainPageView's Xaml  I haved this xaml code to display the DetailsView
    
    
`<v:DetailsView ></v:DetailsView>`

Comment: This correctly displays the DetailsView but the properties do not show the values on the view that are set through MainPageViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your viewmodel? You need that as well, but you are going to need a view as well, which is what you want to bind, unless you do what I love to do in some cases. Anyways you will have to Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for signalling the gui that the property has changed.

```
private DetailsViewModel detailsManager;
public DetailsViewModel DetailsManager
{
    get { return detailsManager; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, detailsManager)) return;
        detailsManager = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // Comment out if no R#
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Edit:**
I read wrong there I think your collection is set in the parents itemssource, so you can implement your property above like a "SelectedItem" for instance. But problem! The items presented in an itemscontrol, in your case an oc with TemplateVM's (we don't know what this is), and the datacontext will be set to the item in the list in the datatemplate.

anyways xaml:

```
<.Resources>
    <local:YourDetailViewConverter x:Key="YourDetailViewConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailManager}">
        <local:DetailsView
            DataContext="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource YourDetailViewConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</.Resources>

<ContentControl>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TemplatesVM}" SelectedItem="{Binding DetailsManager}" Width="{Binding GridWidth}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding NumColumns}"></UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     </ItemsControl>
</ContentControl>
```

You will need to create a IValueConverter that converts your detailviewmodels into their actual view. This can be handy if you have differnt detailviews.

Hope it helps

Cheers

Stian

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comments, the answer is simple.

Just bind the data context of your view like this

```
<v:DetailsView DataContext={Binding DetailsManager}></v:DetailsView>
```

and it should work.